# What are some good fields to research in data science?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I am recently working on my thesis. I had started with recommender systems, but figured out that there is nothing more to optimize in this field since researchers have found around 8.5 RMSE for netflix data-set. Thus I am not going to reach a lot in this field. So I am wondering what are some good field to research on in machine learning or data mining? Or what are some novel and famous fields that researchers are interested in nowadays? I am personally interested in interconnection between nutrition and machine learning. I will appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Best is always Relative :)